# how can i forbid the same file use primefaces fileupload with jsf

Tags: validation, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces with JSFin web,and I don't want user upload the same file.That's like you can't save the same file in a path. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Sure, check it in **your** code after uploading to a temp folder... But better to rely on the content for duplication

Comment: It's not allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know user's local file path: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15201071/1341535). Also a user could rename or move files, and circumvent the file path check. As Kukeltje commented, better compare file content server-side.

If you really want to validate client-side based on file names, then you could override the widget's `validate` method. It's undocumented though, so it can go away in future PrimeFaces versions.

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload mode="advanced" widgetVar="fileup" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            PF('fileup').validate = function(file) {
                if (file.name === 'alreadyuploaded.png')
                    return 'Not this one though'; // return a error message string
                else
                    return null; // allow
            }
        });
    </script>
</h:form>
```

I didn't test this in older non-HTML5 browsers though - p:fileUpload in advanced mode works differently in those.

Comment: I don't want to know the local file path,i just want want to forbid the name and file type(the suffix) can not add again.

Comment: @西门吹雪, amended the answer.

Comment: I have readed your code,and i understand it,but how can i get the "alreadyuploaded.png" real file names(maybe many files),could you explain it more clearly.@Vsevolod Golovanov

Comment: @西门吹雪, when a file is uploaded you get a `FileUploadEvent` on the server. Get names with `event.getFile().getFileName()`, store them in some collection in appropriate scope, and `update` the script. The script should refer to the collection (converted to JS) via EL: `if (file.name === #{myBean.forbiddenFilenamesJSList})`...

Comment: But is there any way that users can not add the same file and with suffix.@Vsevolod Golovanov.